# Should there be a hardlink from `/Users/Users` pointing to `/Users`?

Tags: filesystem, user-account

This is was my `/Users` directory looks like. That `Users` link doesn't seem quite right..

```
matt@viking Users $ pwd
/Users

matt@viking Users $ ls -lA
total 8
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel      0 22 Aug  2015 .localized
drwxr-xr-x+ 11 Guest  _guest   374 11 Nov 18:40 Guest
drwxrwxrwt   5 root   wheel    170 12 Nov 06:42 Shared
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   admin      6 12 Nov 23:10 Users -> /Users
drwxr-xr-x+ 14 dave   staff    476  2 May 21:59 dave
drwxr-xr-x+ 87 matt   staff   2958  2 May 22:09 matt

matt@viking Users $
```

You can then of course go on to do silly things like this..

```
matt@viking Users $ cd Users/Users/Users/Users/Users/Users

matt@viking Users $ pwd
/Users/Users/Users/Users/Users/Users/Users

matt@viking Users $ ls -lA
total 8
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel      0 22 Aug  2015 .localized
drwxr-xr-x+ 11 Guest  _guest   374 11 Nov 18:40 Guest
drwxrwxrwt   5 root   wheel    170 12 Nov 06:42 Shared
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   admin      6 12 Nov 23:10 Users -> /Users
drwxr-xr-x+ 14 dave   staff    476  2 May 21:59 dave
drwxr-xr-x+ 87 matt   staff   2958  2 May 22:09 matt

matt@viking Users $
```

It doesn't seem like the `Users` link should be there, there's a good chance I created it myself by accident; I just can't help but think some service or other might be relying on it being there.

Can I just delete it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to delete it? If not just leave it. And sorry for posting a comment in an answer, I'm not allowed to comment yet...

Comment: You, or someone, created it and it is a symbolic link and can be safely deleted. OS X does not permit the User to create hard links of _directories_ using the `ln` command, it only allows hard links of _files_.

Answer (score 2):

There should not be a link like that. If you truly have a hard link, that's something that's a bit self-referential, snake eating it's own tail recursion, so I'd make sure you have a backup if you're not sure you're deleting the correct link.

From your listing - the link count is 1 so it's probably a sym link and not even a hard link - which means it's safer to delete in reality than in theory above.

I would expect a 2 between the permissions `lrwxr-x-ry-x` and `root` owner if you had a hard link there.

Comment: The "l" in the first column of the `ls -l` listing indicates that it's a symbolic link -- a hard link would have a "d" there (since a hard link is really just the item itself, and in this case the item is a directory).

Comment: @Gordon Davisson, From the `ln` man page, "_Hard links may not normally refer to directories and may not span file systems._", so if it starts with a `d`, e.g. `drwxr-xr-x` it **is** just a directory, not a hard link as hard links of directories are not supported. If you even try to hard link a directory you'll get an message saying `ln: source_file Is a directory` and it doesn't create it.

Comment: @user3439894 That's true on most unixes, but OS X has supported hard-linked directories (on Mac OS Extended volumes) since v10.5, and uses them extensively in Time Machine backups.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, TM does make extensive use of hard links with _files_, more so then hard links of _directories_, as verified by using `ls -li` to get the _inode number_. I reviewed the last 6 months of my TM backups there were a few _directories_ that share the same _inode number_ but consistently the top level _directories_ of the Macintosh HD did not have the same _inode number_ and are not hard links. That said, let me rephrase part of my last comment and say OS  X does not permit the User to create hard links of _directories_ using the `ln` command, it only allows hard links of _files_.